# Alternate error and no-error in python interactive mode

Tags: python

With file xx.py:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __long__(self):
        return long(self.x)

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.x)


y = Foo(22)

print '%d' % y
print '%d' % y
```

Interactive mode:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.7

$ python -i xx.py 
22
22
>>> 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
>>> '%d' % y
'22'
>>> '%d' % y
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
>>> '%d' % y
'22'
>>> '%d' % y
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
```

Why does it alternate between printing '22' and raising a TypeError?

Why does it raise an error on the first carriage return (with no input)?

Thanks.

Comment: Really strange error! I tried this code in Python 2.6.1 on OS X and I couldn't recreate this behavior.

Comment: Problem also exists as stated under Ubuntu 11.04 with Python 2.7.1+.

Comment: It does not matter what is typed at the first prompt (including undefined variables or `raise(Exception())`.  It prints the same `TypeError` error message and not, say, a `NameError` or an `Exception` message.

Comment: Also, `int(y)` consistently prints a `TypeError` (except in the first instance as noted above).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in python!  My guess is it's caused by some leftover cruft from the old string-based exceptions.

The hexadecimal stuff is a red herring, you can also get strange behaviour with simply assigning `y = Foo(1)` and just using `'%d' % y` will exhibit the funny toggling stuff.

You ***should*** get an TypeError at the first `print '0x%x' % y` in your script, because that part is not well-defined.  But somehow the result gets coerced, and it looks like a string-based exception somehow gets...missed, when it probably should have been turned into a `TypeError`.

If this string substitution stuff is buggy then it's one more reason to move to the preferred new method for string formatting, e.g. `print '{0:x}'.format(22)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the issue exists with `'%d'`.  I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

I know why you're getting the error message, it's because you haven't defined an `__int__` method for the class, which is used for quite a few things, including old-style string formatting via `int()`. I seem to recall that `int()` will only work on numeric types, strings and objects that possess an `__int__()` method (although there may be others I've forgotten about).

When you add:

```
def __int__(self):
    return int(self.x)
```

to your class definition, then the error goes away.

If you just want the error to disappear, that's all you need to do.

---

What I'm *not* sure of is why you get the error on *alternate* runs. In fact, you don't have to do anything on the alternate runs, an ENTER key press will cause the error, the same as when you started:

```
pax$ python -i xx.py
0x16
0x16
>>> **ENTER**
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
>>> '%x'%y
'16'
>>> **ENTER**
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
>>> '%x'%y
'16'
>>> **ENTER**
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Foo'
>>> **ENTER**
>>> **ENTER**
>>> **ENTER**
>>>
```

Comment: I realize that adding a __int__ method would make the error message go away.  But my question is why does python alternate between an error and no error with the given class definition.  It should either consistently error or it should consistently call the __long__ method.